# MEF doesn't discover assemblies when published to live

Tags: mef

I have a WCF service which use MEF to discover assemblies used in bin folder. When i run the WCF service in local a client application can access it without problem all the assemblies are discovered by MEF but when i publish the WCF service to Live server MEF doesn't discover some assemblies at run time i get 
Object Reference errors.Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: We need to see some more details... Show how you are importing your assemblies etc.

Comment: Thanks for you response I actually resolved the issue using Mefx and log4net it was some dll weren't copied correctly to live when publishing and some access rights issues

Comment: I would close this if you have sorted the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved the issue using Mefx and log4net it was some dll weren't copied correctly to live when publishing and some access rights issues

If anybody get this issue they should use MEFx here is the links that helped me

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576068(v=vs.110).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx